# proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db when trying to open a QGIS project in Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to write a standalone QGIS script that opens an existing QGIS Project in Python3.
Upon Calling `project.read('filename.qgz')` (projct being an instance of QgsProject) I get the following errors:

```
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
```

I have set the PROJ_LIB environment variable to the directory proj.db resides in (%qgisPath%\share\proj), but that doesn't change anything.

I'm on Windows 10, running QGIS 3.14, but I had the same problem in QGIS 3.10

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I just struggled with the same error. Seems like there are some issues in the way gdal and python is currently set up. I've added the  PROJ_DEBUG = 3 to my environment variables and could see that even though with PROJ_LIB environment it still points to (C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/python\profiles\default/proj\proj.db), so I copied the proj.db to that location. See the thread: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1735